# recursive directory scanning with different sorting

Tags: php, list, sorting, recursion

I am using this script for scanning through my directories.

```
function listFolderFiles($dir) {
    $ffs = scandir($dir, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff) {
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..') {
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
                echo '<li>'.$ff;
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            } else {                                    
                echo '<li><a href="'.$dir.'/'.$ff.'" target="_blank">'.$ff.'</a>';
            }
            echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    listFolderFiles('upload/files/');
```

The directory structury is always the same: first you got the year as directory (2013, 2014, ...) and in those directories you got a bunch of documents.

I want to start the listing with the most recent year (so descending) but I want the documents to be ascending.

Can this code be altered so that only the highest levels are sorted descending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the sorting mode to the function.

```
function listFolderFiles($dir, $sort = SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING) {
    $ffs = scandir($dir, $sort);
    echo '<ul>'; 
    foreach($ffs as $ff) {
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..') {
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) { 
                echo '<li>'.$ff; 
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff, SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING);
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="'.$dir.'/'.$ff.'" target="_blank">'.$ff.'</a>';
            } echo '</li>';
        }
    } echo '</ul>';
}
```

The default value makes it possible to call the function like you do currently.

Comment: Oh indeed...I was looking to put a counter on it but offcourse it the value is always set to default when calling the function again...